# Kubernetes Helm Redis Google Cloud MemoryStore - Service vs Endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, google-cloud-memorystore

I'm looking to configure Redis for Sidekiq and Rails in k8s. Using Google Cloud Memory Store with an IP address.

I have a helm template like the following (with gcpRedisMemorystore specified separately) - My question is what does the Service object add to the system? Is it necessary or does the Endpoint provide all the needed access?

charts/app/templates/app-memorystore.service.yaml

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: app-memorystore
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: redis
    port: {{ .Values.gcpredis.port }}
    protocol: TCP
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: app-memorystore
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: {{ .Values.gcpredis.ip }}
  ports:
  - port: {{ .Values.gcpredis.port }}
    name: redis
    protocol: TCP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you still need it.

Generally speaking, the Service is the name which is consumed by applications to connect to an Endpoint. Usually, a Service with a selector will automatically create a corresponding endpoint with the IP addresses of the Pods found by the selector.

When you define a Service without a selector you need to give the corresponding Endpoint of the same name so the Service has somewhere to go. This bit of information is in documentation but a bit buried. At https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#without-selectors it is mentioned in the second bullet point for headless services without selectors:

> For headless services that do not define selectors, the endpoints controller does not create Endpoints records. However, the DNS system looks for and configures either:
>
> - CNAME records for ExternalName-type services.
> - A records for any Endpoints that share a name with the service, for all other types.

Comment: Upvoted but saying `When you define a "headless" Service like this you need to give the corresponding Endpoint of the same name so the Service has somewhere to go.` is misleading. As mentioned in your link, headless services can also have selectors. What you said applies to services without selectors, whether they are headless or not.

Comment: Quoting the link: `Because this service has no selector, the corresponding Endpoint object will not be created automatically. You can manually map the service to the network address and port where it’s running, by adding an Endpoint object manually`

Comment: I modified the answer to clarify a bit.

Comment: Thank you! Something that I am having trouble understanding is what selectors and no-selectors mean, and how selectors are used. This doc about the different Service types helps a little: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/ "A Service created without selector will also not create the corresponding Endpoints object"